# How to redirect STDOUT of subscript into variable in ruby 2.1.6

Tags: ruby, stdout

Here is my full code so far:

```
if ARGV.size == 0
    print "Set a library name as parameter"
else
    dir = ARGV[0]
    begin
        Dir.chdir "#{dir}"
    rescue
        print "No such library"
    else
        filelist = Dir.glob "*.rb"
        outfile = "result"
        i = 0
        while i < filelist.size do
            filename = filelist[i]
            output = load "./#{filename}"
            if output == 1
                File.open(outfile, 'a+') { |file| file.write("#{filename}")}
            end
            i += 1
        end
    end
end
```

The subscripts I'm trying to run can either contain this: `print "1"` or this: `print "0"`.

I want to write to a "result" file

> filename :: OK

if it is `print "1"`, and

> filename :: WRONG

if it is `print "2"`.

My problem is that `output` always equals `true` instead of `1` or `0`. How could I redirect the subscript's `STDOUT` to the `output` variable?

Comment: It returns `true`, because that's the returning value of `load` when it successfully loads a *.rb file. It's not the output of script.

Comment: @lcguida: Yes, I figured that much. But how can I redirect the STDOUT, or what other command should I use instead of `load` to run the subscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the output :

```
output = `ruby #{filename}`
```

Note : It returns a string, but you are comparing output to a number. Do the necessary conversions.

Comment: It doesn't work. It says: **No such file or directory - ruby test1.rb (Errno::ENOENT)**

Comment: It will work if the file named 'test1.rb' is in the current working directory. Are you sure that the file is present in the current working directory at the point where it tries to run it ?

Comment: Yes it is definitely there, it wouldn't even know what file to complain about if it didn't read the filelist beforehand with `Dir.glob "*.rb"`. I also check the working directory with `puts Dir.pwd` in the previous line, and it is correct.
I am on Windows 8.1 and when I type in ruby into the command line, it says **'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file**. Could it have something to do with that?

Comment: Ok, that was the problem. I added ruby to PATH with : `PATH=C:\Ruby21\bin;%PATH%` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks (``) to run your script and capture its output as a string.

```
`ruby somescript.rb`
# "1"
```

A hackier approach, but which actually works with `load`, is to overwrite `$stdout` before loading the script.

```
require 'stringio'
output = StringIO.new
stdout = $stdout

begin
  $stdout = output
  load 'somescript.rb'
ensure
  $stdout = stdout
end
output.string
# "1"
```